# How to remove comments from R (Rstudio) output?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like that R comments appear on the script file but not on the console.

```
1 + 1 # just a comment
```

Produces this:

```
> 1 + 1 # just a comment   
[1] 2
```

But I would like to get just

```
> 1 + 1 
[1] 2
```

Where can I modify the settings to get what I want?

The reason is because sometimes I use long comments and they confuse the output.

PD: My question is not related with knitr nor markdown, it's just a general R and Rstudio question.

Comment: Not sure that's an option at the moment. Why not just put the comment above the line instead of on the same line?

Comment: If you're ok with none of your code showing in the console (as in only output gets displayed in the console), you can hit the top right of your script panel and click `Source`, or alternatively use `Ctrl + Shift + S`